# Datatables.js Hyperlink Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using DataTables.js and need to have a each cell in a column a clickable url. For now I'm trying to have it to go to google.com.

I'm struggling to get it to work and after ready several tutorials still no closer, my code is as below;

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "Requisitions.aspx/GetMyRequisitions",
    method: "POST",
    data: '{"ReqId":"' + reqId + '", "Title": "' + reqTitle + '", "PrimaryHiringManager": "' + reqHiringManager + '", "StartDate": "' + reqStartDate + '", "Status": "' + reqStatus + '", "Applicants": "' + reqApplicants + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        jQuery('#MyRequisitions').DataTable({
            data: data.d,
            retrieve: true,
            order: [[5, "desc"]],
            responsive: true,

            column:
                [
                    { "data": "ReqId" },
                    {
                        "data": "Title",
                        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                data = '<a href="https://www.google.com/"></a>';
                            return data;
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "PrimaryHiringManager" },
                    { "data": "StartDate" },
                    { "data": "Status" },
                    { "data": "Applicants" }
                ]
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: "*...clickable url to go to different records etc*" You must be more specific than that. And show what you have tried.

Comment: That's the general idea long term, at the moment I'm simply trying to get it to go to google

Comment: OK, if that is the goal  your code is fine, but I will recommend you to give the hyperlink a clickable anchor name instead of nothing, i.e `return  '<a href="https://www.google.com/" target=_blank>google</a>'` :)

Comment: @davidkonrad there's already data pulled into the actual Title cell so I really just want to use that as the anchor text and click it and get to google.com

Comment: Then  `return '<a href="https://www.google.com/" target=_blank>'+data+'</a>'` When you are using the `render()`callback  you override all rendering completely, it will not render out `Title` unless you include it in the return value yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this dear

```
{"data": "Title",
                     "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="#" onclick="selectCompany([' + data + '])">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                     },
```

Comment: onclick event call a javascript function and pass data to function you try it in your way

Answer (score 0):

> Hyperlink with passing value to it

```
{  
"render": function (data, type, full, meta)  
{ return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/Demo/Edit/' + full.CustomerID + '">Edit</a>'; }  
}
```

> On Click of Hyperlink calling function

```
{  
data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {  
return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.CustomerID + "'); >Delete</a>";  
}  
},

function DeleteData(CustomerID) {  
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ...?")) {  

        }  
        else {  
            return false;  
        }  
    }
```

> Output

[image: Output]

> Link of Article if you want more Details

[Link to Datatables Grid Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/)